# Is it possible to build or purchase a DC to DC converter with high power inputs and outputs?

Tags: voltage, dc-motor, boost

I am currently working on a project that involves connecting a 24 V battery system to an electric motor I purchased. Ideally I would like to run the electric motor at 48 V and around 400 A for maximum torque output. When I look online for off the shelf DC to DC boost converters I'm seeing that many products are maxed out at currents around 5 A. Are there any suggestions for where I can find an efficient boost converter that can operate at high power inputs and outputs?

Comment: 800A from 24V is rather a challenge.. Why don't you just double up the batteries ???

Comment: I'm restricted on the voltage of my source unfortunately. Currently I'm trying to understand if this endeavor is even possible.

Comment: @James, can you use one battery for +24 and one for -24 V?

Comment: I'll have to think about that for a bit. Does that suggest that a boost converter would not be recommended in this scenario?

Comment: Consider you're asking for 19 kW of power, and switching converters are typically no more than 95% efficient...your converter is going to need to have a heatsink for 1 kW itself.

Comment: Assuming you can achieve 95% efficiency with such massive currents running around. I imagine there are ways to do this, but I don't expect they have much in common with the typical 10-100 W DC-DC boost converter.

Comment: even if you can find one at 95% efficiency you will still be dumping almost a kilowatt in heat.

Comment: I can't imagine it wouldn't be cheaper just to buy a second battery pack, even if it's a huge one.

Comment: Or see if you can find the same motor with a 24V winding.

Comment: Yeah there will definitely be a large amount of heat generation in this conversion. Luckily I'm more knowledgeable about heat transfer so that can be taken care of. I'll try looking into specialty stores to see if they might carry such a part. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Possible... probably, sensible... not so much.

Comment: Guess we'll have to look down a different avenue then in the project. Thanks everyone for the fast inputs!

Comment: "I would like to run the electric motor at 48 V and around 400 A for maximum torque output." - torque is produced by _current_, not voltage.

Comment: Rewinding the motor for 24V is probably your best bet, as Trevor suggests.

Comment: Better change the motor that runs at higher voltage and less current. For 800A, you need fat cables as well. You have to use multiple batteries so that drain per battery is acceptable. The discharge efficiency of a battery drops with higher current draw. Low voltage is generally used for low power or safety reasons.

Answer (score 0):

[I know its not what your looking for but this one can do 170A](http://www.mouser.co.za/Search/m_ProductDetail.aspx?Vicor%2FNBM6123T60E12A7T0R%2F&qs=sGAEpiMZZMsc0tfZmXiUnd1YwnPIr6zkQ2Uvi6PdZKfOBdEY709Q%2FA%3D%3D) at 5V, just to show you do get high current converters. You can get higher current /power converters(20Kw+) but i think this is going to end up being a solution that costs way too much.